# Can Reporting services be installed on a Windows server 2008 R2 SP1 Enterprise edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Am currently working through the mspress book to do the exam 70-462 and one of the questions asks what versions of sql and windows server reporting services can be installed on.

I was quite shocked to find that it said that Reporting services cannot be installed on a windows server 2008 R2 SP1 for SQL Enterprise edition.

I really dont see how this could be the case and having trawled through the msdn documentation cannot find any evidence to support this.

Can anyone shine any light on whether this is the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install it on Windows Server 2008 R2 according to the following paragraph found on the link below it:

"Starting in SQL Server 2008 R2, the Reporting Services component no longer supports Itanium-based servers running Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2003 R2. Reporting Services continues to support other 64-bit operating systems, including Windows Server°2008 for Itanium-Based Systems and Windows Server°2008°R2 for Itanium-Based Systems. To upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 from a SQL Server 2008 installation with Reporting Services on an Itanium-based system edition of Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2003 R2, you must first upgrade the operating system."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx

It is under:  Processor, Memory, and Operating System Requirements.

Comment: Yeah i am thinking it is maybe a typo in the book as i cant see an enterprise level software edition not supporting it on a windows server 2008 box. Thanks for the quote on that!